# Flatpickr Appending issue

Tags: jquery, flatpickr

I am using a plugin known as Flatpickr. It works fine but when i add behavior of  on click and try to append it to another div it display multiple text box there.
its weird, now what i need to do now, shall i find flatpicr in that div and then remove it if it has more than. or There is any other alternative solution for this.

```
<form id="taskForm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="taskContent">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Date Range<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control flatpickr" placeholder="Select Date">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div id="taskEmpty">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-1 pull-right text-right">
                            <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="addTask" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer;"></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">Create</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is the script

```
flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
    enableTime: true,
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "j- M- Y h:i K",
    "mode": "range"
});

$("#addTask").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var clone = $(".taskContent").clone();
    $("#taskEmpty").html(clone);
    //initialize date again
    flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
        enableTime: true,
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "j- M- Y h:i K",
        "mode": "range"
    });

});
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh1kbvgL/)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like calling flatpickr(".flatpickr"); creates duplicate instances.

```
const fpConf = {
enableTime: true,
altInput: true,
altFormat: "j- M- Y h:i K",
"mode": "range",
wrap: true,
allowInput: true
};

var clone = $(".taskContent").clone();

flatpickr(".taskContent .input-group", fpConf);

$("#addTask").on("click", function(event){
event.stopPropagation();

const newClone = clone.clone();
$("#taskEmpty").append(newClone);
$(newClone).find(".input-group").flatpickr(fpConf);
});
```

This issue fixed by **chmln** creator of the flatpicker plugin.
Thanks to him. Great Work.....